# nodejs child_process spawned a subprocess, the subprocess not show console window

Tags: node.js

I write nodejs code, use child_process.spawn() method create a subprocess, but the subprocess does not show its console window, how to show it?

```js
'use stricts';

let process = require('process');
let child_process = require('child_process');

var subprocess = child_process.spawn(
    'CSharpProg.exe', [] , 
    {   
        windowsHide: false
    });
subprocess.stdout.on('data', d => console.log(d.toString('utf8')));

process.stdin.on('data', d => subprocess.stdin.write(d));
```

I expec the spawned subprocess can have its own console window shown.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What did you mean by `not show its console window,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make subprocess show its own console window (on Windows environment), you need to set option `shell` and `detached` as `true`. The default value of option `windowsHide` is `false`, so it's not necessary to set it again.

I tested the following code and it works on Windows 10 with Node.js v10.16.0:

```
var subprocess = child_process.spawn('node', ['test2.js'], {
    shell: true,
    detached: true
});
```

Comment: yes, i just mean that, I want to communicate between these two process.  Thanks!

Comment: Watch out for spaces in path names on Windows. That will cause the spawn to stealth fail.

Comment: How about Linux ? I have shell: true and detached: true, but I don't see the console window in my Linux Ubuntu. It works perfectly for Windows.